# Como fazer carregamento aleatório de imagens?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8-1

Como faço o carregamento aleatório de imagens no background de uma página do *app*, para que cada vez que o usuário entre em uma determinada página o fundo alterne entre as imagens ?

Como devo proceder para fazer isso?

Comment: Ele vai ficar alternando entre as imagens enquanto está na página ou sempre que ele entra na página carregará um fundo aleatório?

Comment: sempre que ele entra na página carregará um fundo aleatório

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie um método `private` na página que terá esse efeito no background, no caso do exemplo chama-se `Pagina1`.

```
private void RandomImage()
{
      Random random = new Random();
      String nameim = random.Next(1, 3).ToString() + ".jpg";
      Uri uri = new Uri("ms-appx:/Assets/" + nameim, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
      ImageBrush img = new ImageBrush();
      img.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(uri);
      this.Background = img;
}
```

Porque eu coloque no `Next(1,3)` do `Random`?

Dentro da `pasta` `Assests` tem duas imagens com os nomes respectivos `1.jpg` e `2.jpg`, então, no exemplo só tenho essas imagens numeradas para criar o efeito aleatório. Se tiver mais imagens então vai ter que aumentar o número 3 para o número de `(imagens + 1)` e perceba que são números sequencias.

Para funcionar coloque essa método `RandomImage()` dentro do seu `Construtor` abaixo do `InitializeComponent()`:

```
public Pagina1()
{
     this.InitializeComponent();
     this.RandomImage();
}
```

A partir disso todas as vezes que carregar a `Pagina1`, o `background` mudará conforme o número gerado pelo `Random`.

*Referência*

- [Método Random.Next (Int32, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx)